# box shadow with after selector

Tags: css

How to add a new `box-shadow` effect on an alement with `::after`

On the last element I both want the outer dark frame and the white inner frame

https://jsfiddle.net/6r4vpt0j/

```
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li">test</li>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li now">test</li>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li selected">test</li>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li now selected">test</li>
</ul>

ul {
  list-style:none outside none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.dropdown_calendar_li {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
  background:#aaa
}

.dropdown_calendar_li.now,
.dropdown_calendar_li.now.selected {
    box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #1f1f1f;
}

.dropdown_calendar_li.now.selected::after {
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #fff;
}
```

Comment: Pseudo elements need at minimum `content: ""`. They also need dimensions like any other element otherwise they won't be displayed.

Comment: Multiple `box-shadow` can be added by just separating using a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the changes:

1. `.dropdown_calendar_li` need `position:relative;`

so that

2. `dropdown_calendar_li.now.selected::after` can handle `position: absolute;`

and

3. `:after` elements need a `content: ''` and some `display` and `size` properties in this case.

```css
ul {
  list-style:none outside none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.dropdown_calendar_li {
  position: relative;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px;
  background:#aaa
}

.dropdown_calendar_li.now,
.dropdown_calendar_li.now.selected {
 box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #1f1f1f;
}

.dropdown_calendar_li.now.selected::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li">test</li>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li now">test</li>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li selected">test</li>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li now selected">test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo elements need at minimum `content: ""`. They also need dimensions like any other element otherwise they won't be displayed.

In your case you can simply use two box shadows on the last element and remove the pseudo element altogether.

```css
ul {
  list-style:none outside none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.dropdown_calendar_li {
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px;
  background:#aaa
}

.dropdown_calendar_li.now {
 box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #1f1f1f;
}

.dropdown_calendar_li.now.selected {
    box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #1f1f1f, inset 0 0 0 2px #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li">test</li>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li now">test</li>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li selected">test</li>
  <li class="dropdown_calendar_li now selected">test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: there is also a white inner frame on the second.. I only want it on the last element

Comment: the classes must define which has the inner frame.. not `last:-child`

Comment: Then remove `:last-child`. I've given you an example. It shouldn't be difficult for you to work out how to modify your own code.

Answer (score -1):

For ::after you need to add content : "" in the css. Try this

```
.dropdown_calendar_li.now.selected::after {
  content: "";
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #fff;
 }
```